# How to import csv into custom modules? - in SugarCRM

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

Is it possible to import .csv fields into custom created modules in SugarCRM?

I have created several custom modules, but I can't find an import button for csv fields.

Thanks!

OK, **I've just found a working solution**:
Link: http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/f148/how-add-import-option-custom-modules-45612/

Add the below line in modules//.php file.

Code:

```
var $importable = true;
```

Create the file menu.ext.php in "custom\modules\\Ext\Menus" with below code.

Code:

```
<?php

if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point'); 

if(ACLController::checkAccess('<Module Name>', 'import', true))     $module_menu[]=Array("index.php?module=Import&action=Step1&import_module=<Module Name>&return_module=<Module Name>&return_action=index", "Import","Import", '<Module Name>');

?>
```

This will add import menu item in the shortcut menu.

Comment: I have taken the MySQL-tag out since MySQL-experts won't be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility (way easier) is to check the button for "Importing" when building a new custom module via the module builder!

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be old but you can download a sample when you click import and it will show you how to do this.  It will show your custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the solution. Only one thing, the rigth route at "Create the file menu.ext.php in "custom\modules\Ext\Menus" with below code" is "custom\Extension\modules\Ext\Menus"

With this, it work fine for me.